# Migrating from ehcache to redis: equivalent of ehcache setTimeToIdle() in redis

Tags: java, redis, ehcache

I am migrating from ehcache to redis. In ehcache has default method to set idle time (setTimeToIdle() not setTimeToLive() ) for a key. Is there any same equivalent to set idle time in redis?? If not any work aroung to acheive the same?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a command in Redis, you can only set the time to live. But you can do an easy workaround, you would have to use 2 commands, first set the new ttl and then return the key. And you want those 2 commands to be atomic, so you can use a lua script or a transaction (with MULTI http://redis.io/commands/multi). 
 Here is an example of lua script that checks if the 'key' exists if yes sets an expire of 10 seconds and returns the value, else returns -1:

```
local redis_key = redis.call('get', 'key')
if redis_key then 
    redis.call('expire', 'key', '10')
    return redis_key
end
return -1
```

You would need to push such a script to redis using http://redis.io/commands/eval